# Conflicting implementations of traits in rust

Tags: rust, traits

My code is :

```
pub trait TestTrait<T> {}

impl TestTrait<&Series> for DataFrame {}

impl <T> TestTrait<T> for DataFrame
where 
    T: NumericNative,
{}
```

here is error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `TestTrait<&polars::prelude::Series>` for type `polars::prelude::DataFrame`
 --> src/main.rs:7:1
  |
5 | impl TestTrait<&Series> for DataFrame {}
  | ------------------------------------- first implementation here
6 |
7 | impl<T> TestTrait<T> for DataFrame where T: NumericNative {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `polars::prelude::DataFrame`
  |
  = note: upstream crates may add a new impl of trait `polars::prelude::NumericNative` for type `&polars::prelude::Series` in future versions

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
```

while there is a similar implement in polars' Series, why My code can't work.
here is polars Series source code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paJlY.jpg)

Comment: `impl TestTrait<&Series> for DataFrame {}` doesn't make sense because your `TestTrait` trait has no generic type parameter. Your second implementation also tries to constrain a generic type `T` that doesn't exist.

Comment: it just write a test trait, i tried a real trait, it can't work too

Comment: Please post an actual minimal example that actually shows the actual error. Ideally with an actual Rust Playground link.

Comment: My point is that `impl TestTrait<&Series> for DataFrame {}` won't work _even without the second impl_ because it passes a generic type argument to something that doesn't have one.  Likewise, the second impl won't work _even without the first impl_ because it tries to constrain a non-existent generic type argument.

Comment: without the first implementation, it can work,  and went through the compiler. I just tried it

Comment: @cdhowie I see it, `impl TestTrait<&Series> for DataFrame {}` does wrong, the source is `impl <T> TestTrait<T> for DataFrame
where 
    T: NumericNative,
{}` i don't why after posted turn to `impl TestTrait<&Series> for DataFrame {}`, sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 2):

The `&Series` struct and `NumericNative` trait are both from the same foreign crate.

It's possible that `&Series` will, at some point in the future, be provided with an implementation of `NumericNative`, which would cause your implementations of `TestTrait` to conflict with each other. Of course, it almost definitely won't, but the compiler has no way of understanding the logical intentions of traits and structs from foreign crates.

If it was possible to implement a trait for a type `T` which implements a foreign trait, and also for a foreign type from the same crate which is technically eligible to have an implementation of that same foreign trait in future, then adding trait implementations in that foreign crate would always be a breaking change.

If you want to get around this, you'll probably have to use the [new type idom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html), which would look something like this (of course, you may need to modify it for your specific use case):

```rust
pub trait TestTrait<T> {}

impl TestTrait<MySeries<'_>> for DataFrame {}

impl<T> TestTrait<T> for DataFrame
where
    T: NumericNative,
{}

// The "New type" idiom
pub struct MySeries<'a> (&'a Series);

impl AsRef<Series> for MySeries<'_> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Series {
        self.0
    }
}
```

Comment: cool, excatly what i need